Is it possible to load ViewContext outside of a view?
Is it possible to get ViewContext outside of a view?
I have a class which I include in ViewImports, but I get an error when I try to load ViewContext (ViewContext is null).
Or do I have to implement it in a tag helper?
ViewUtility:
public sealed class ViewUtility : IViewUtility
{
    private readonly IHtmlHelper _htmlHelper;

    public ViewUtility(IHtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        _htmlHelper = htmlHelper;

        (this.HtmlHelper as IViewContextAware).Contextualize(this.ViewContext);
    }

    [ViewContext]
    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }
    public ViewDataDictionary ViewData => this.ViewContext.ViewData;
    
    public IHtmlHelper HtmlHelper => _htmlHelper;
}

ViewImports:
@using SL.Assets.Core.Components.Utility;

@inject IViewUtility ViewUtility


How should we understand this sentence Is it possible to load ViewContext outside of a view??

As we know, what you add in _ViewImports should be related to custom taghelper, which is obviously used for pages. So how to understand outside of a view?  Or you can tell us your needs more clearly.

ViewUtility is always accessed in a View, so I was wondering if it's possible to get the ViewContext from the current view that ViewUtility is accessed from. It's not a big deal, just wondering

Could you please help me confirm if this is what you want?

@JasonPan yes kinda. thanks! I'll look into it

As an answer to the question:

Is it possible to load "ViewContext" outside of a view?

we can briefly say:

Yes, it is possible using the "MVC ViewEngine", as I will explain below, but in my opinion, this may be Anti-Pattern.

In "MVC", one of the goals is to separate the model and the view. It is logical to use the model in the view, but if you mean to use the information of the view inside the model, it may destroy the "MVC" structure to some extent.
On the other hand, considering that "ViewContext" depends on the information of the controller, the view name and the model object, it will actually be parametric. So if we want, for example, to have a service that can extract the "ViewContext" anywhere without any additional parameters, it is probably not possible.
Actually it is good to use "ViewContext" in "cshtml" files.
In any case, according to this Stack Overflow question, for example if we want to have a "ViewContext" in the controller. We can add the following code to the project. For example, an "ASP .NET Core Web App (Model-View-Controller)" project in ".NET 6" for "Visual Studio 2022".
ControllerExtensions:
public static class ControllerExtensions
{
    public static ViewContext? GetViewContext<TModel>(this Controller controller, string viewName, TModel model, bool isPartial = false)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName)) 
        {
            controller.ViewData.Model = model;

            using var writer = new StringWriter();
            var viewEngine = controller.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(ICompositeViewEngine)) as ICompositeViewEngine;
            var isMainPage = !isPartial;
            var viewResult = viewEngine?.FindView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName, isMainPage);

            if (viewResult?.Success == true)
            {
                ViewContext viewContext = new(
                    controller.ControllerContext,
                    viewResult.View,
                    controller.ViewData,
                    controller.TempData,
                    writer,
                    new HtmlHelperOptions()
                );
                return viewContext;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

Sample action method in controller class:
public IActionResult SomeActionMethod()
{
    var TestModelData = new { };
    var viewContextForIndexPage = this.GetViewContext("Index", TestModelData);
    return View();
}


very interesting solution! I'll look into it later. I don't have a good reason for wanting to access View State from an external class, but it's just one of those "is it possible?" questions. thanks!

Here is the detailed steps for you, it can fix the ViewContext  null issue.
IViewUtility.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;

namespace MyMvcProject.Models
{
    public interface IViewUtility
    {
        ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

        ViewDataDictionary ViewData { get; }

        string RenderMessage(ViewContext viewContext);
    }
}

ViewUtility.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;

namespace MyMvcProject.Models
{
    public sealed class ViewUtility : IViewUtility
    {

        public ViewUtility()
        {
        }

        [ViewContext]
        public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

        public ViewDataDictionary ViewData => this.ViewContext.ViewData;
        // Not using IHtmlHelper here, so comment it
        //public IHtmlHelper HtmlHelper => _htmlHelper;
        // For testing
        public string RenderMessage(ViewContext viewContext)
        {
            if (viewContext != null && viewContext.View != null)
            {
                return $"View Name: {viewContext.View.Path}";
            }
            return "ViewContext is not available.";
        }
    }

}

_ViewImports.cshtml
@using MyMvcProject
@using MyMvcProject.Models
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@inject MyMvcProject.Models.IViewUtility ViewUtility

Program.cs
using MyMvcProject.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// Register it 
builder.Services.AddScoped<IViewUtility,ViewUtility>();
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();

Home/Index.cshtml
@model dynamic
@inject MyMvcProject.Models.IViewUtility ViewUtility

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div>
    <h1>Welcome to the Home Page!</h1>
    <p>@ViewUtility.RenderMessage(ViewContext)</p>
</div>

Test Result



do you think it's possible to do the same without having to pass the ViewContext from the View? Getting ViewContext for the current showing View from code behind in utility class

@SteinLundbeckTech Not sure, as we know all the things we have tried are used for pages (belongs to custom taghelper), so you should know what your needs, I mean what you want to get in utility class.

what I really want is to have ViewContext for current view as a service and just inject it where I need it, or get it from ActionContext

@SteinLundbeckTech Will check it when I am free.

HtmlHelper has a ViewContext property, but I haven't tested it fully yet

@SteinLundbeckTech ViewContext only exists when the view is rendered. If you want to get view-related content in a non-view environment, you can create a context related to ViewContext in the middleware.

ah ok I see. lately I've been looking into View Components, and it looks like they can access current View Context which is what I'm looking for. meanng, it would be great to be able to just inject it where you needed it, but View Components are better than nothing
